# Blank Windows Explorer Window

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-explorer

Simply put, my Windows Explorer seems to be messed up. I've run a virus scan, sfc /scannow, and several other checks. I also uninstalled DAEMON Tools Lite, but all to no avail. I'm wondering if this can be fixed without reinstalling windows, as I am still waiting on some discs.
Here's a picture of what seems to be happening:

[image]

I can navigate directories just fine using the command prompt, but I can't actually do anything involving Windows Explorer, including opening up the control panel or running any apps from there. Typing something into the address bar opens up another window which is also broken.

Running Windows 7 Professional edition

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're in Test Mode (a precaution for running unsigned drivers).

Microsoft released a fix for this.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2509241

Once you run the fix does the problem go away?